# how to reopen Messages tools window in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij and when I was trying to check a message, by mistake I closed it. I tried reopening it from View -> Tools Window -> Messages, but that's disabled.
Can someone please let me know how do I enable/reopen it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what type of message? error log or what?

Comment: messages when I synchronise the project/run some tests etc..somehow that 'Messages ' is disabled from the View -> Tools window

Comment: Can you not view it by pressing Alt + 0?

Comment: or try rebuilding it - they'll come back then

Comment: Alt + 0 doesn't work..rebuilding???

Comment: Yes "Rebuild Project"